# Symfony2: Controller class not found (in default, generated file)

Tags: php, symfony, intellij-idea

I have started a Symfony2 tutorial, and created a default project using Intellij Idea.

When I try to run the project, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller' not found in
C:\Users\[...]\SymfonyTraining\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
on line 10
```

It relates to the following file:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ]);
    }
}

?>
```

All the answers I found were about missing namespace or use, or typos, but it doesn't seems to be it.

Any idea ?

(maybe it's just something obvious I don't see)

Comment: How do you run the project? Are you using some IDE function to "run project" that opens up that spesific file in a browser, or are you using some web server that properly serves app.php/app_dev.php?

Comment: Have you did the composer install, in order to have the autoloader ready?

Comment: I used the IDE's option "Run project", because I had trouble with the server and I wanted to go there step by step.
I had the composer installed, is there something specific to do to get the autoloader ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the autoloader. You can use "dump-autoload" to do that without having to go through an install or update
So try to executing this command:

> composer dump-autoload

Comment: Do you mean in the console ? Isn't there something I should install first, because I get a "command unknown error".

Comment: command unknown error that means the composer isn't defined global, try : php composer.phar dump-autoload . But check if the php is defined in environement variable and check the existence of composer.phar in your project root

Comment: Thank you, the command worked and displayed "Generating autoload files". However, the same error ("Class [...]/Controller not found) still appears when I run the project.

Comment: Try clear caches (php app/console cache:clear --env=prod) or access to page with dev environment : (domainname/app_dev.php)